# Find Coordinates of TextField in ScrollView Relative to Screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a large number of `UITextField` inside `UIScrollView`, I want to check the coordinate of
`UITextField` relative to the screen, in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method and move up the screen only if the keyboard will hide the `UITextField`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the absolute position of your text field like below:

```
    CGRect absoluteframe = [mytextfield convertRect:mytextfield.frame toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

then use that to test if it goes below some specific position (e.g. where the keyboard starts) and then scroll the scrollview accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

in  the  `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate

```
 float y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + textField.frame.origin.y;
    float x = scrollView.contentOffset.x + textField.frame.origin.x;

NSLog(@"x Position is :%f , y position is : %f",x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 solution:**

```
let absoluteframe: CGRect = (activeField?.convert(activeField!.frame, to: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow))!
```