# Get X/Y coordinates of UI Element on iphone screen - NOT UIView?

Tags: ios, screen

I understand that in order to get the x or y coordinates of a UI Element you can use something like button.center.y or self.view.frame.size.height to get the height of your UIView).  But, if I understand all this correctly, all of this is within the bounds of a UIView.

How do you obtain the same information in terms of the iPhone screen itself?

Maybe something like:

```
screen.view.frame.size.height
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  My UIElements are on a UIScrollView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140300/find-coordinates-of-textfield-in-scrollview-relative-to-screen

Answer (score 6):

Convert the point from your view's coordinate system to the enclosing window's coordinate system, and then convert that point from the window to the screen.
Use [`-[UIView convertPoint:toView:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:) and [`-[UIWindow convertPoint:toWindow:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWindow/convertPoint:toWindow:)

```
 UIWindow* myWindow = myView.window;
 CGPoint pointInWindow = [myView convertPoint:pointInMyView toView:myWindow];
     // note: toView:nil also works
 CGPoint pointInScreen = [myWindow convertPoint:pointInWindow toWindow:nil];
```

By the way, an important point: view properties like [`center`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center) and [`frame`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) are relative to the view's *superview's* coordinate system. So, to convert a view's center to the screen:

```
 CGPoint pointInWindow = [myView.superview convertPoint:myView.center toView:nil];
 CGPoint pointInScreen = [myView.window convertPoint:pointInWindow toWindow:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I will look into the window stuff.
Also, yes, I heard about the frames vs. bounds stuff in my searches.  I will refresh my memory and make sure I have those differences down. :)  Thanks again!
BTW:  Thanks for the doc links - very useful.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my UIView is, more accurately, a UIScrolLView.  It seems convertPoint:toView: doesn't exist for this?

Comment: `UIScrollView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so it has all of the methods implemented by `UIView`, including `-convertPoint:toView:.` You can just call the method. You don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  My usage was wonky.  It is working now. :)